# How to extract the extract specific key from an dictionaries?

Tags: python

hello i'm at the beginning with python and while I was programming I ran into this problem :

```
pidred = 4042629
pidblue = 4038785

variantList = {'40426296': '5', '40387858': '6', '40387857': '5.5', '40387856': '5', '40387854': '4', '40387852': '3'}

variant_keys = list(variantList)
```

I would like to extract every key of the list variant that contains pidblue, but I am stuck... how can I do it?
Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "every key of the list variant"? Keys in a dictionary can't be repeated.

Comment: @vestronge i've this error 
print(variantList[str(pidblue)])
KeyError: '4038785'

Comment: @Barmar i want to print all the variantList.keys() that contains pidblue(4038785) so i'm expecting a list of this value : 40387858; 40387857; 40387856; 40387854; 40387852

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension

```
strblue = str(pidblue)
blue_keys = [key for key in variantList if strblue in key]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the item contains pidblue and appends it to contains_pidblue

```
contains_pidblue=[]
for item in variant_keys:
    if str(pidblue) in item:
        contains_pidblue.append(item)
```